# Space Marine Charge & Rapid Fire

Tags: warhammer-40k

In the 6th edition, the "Declare Charge" rule specifies that if the unit shot a *Rapid Fire* weapon then they can't charge.

Tactical Space Marines have a bolter (24ps range) and a bolter pistol (12ps range) as basic equipment.

I understand that within a 12ps range, I can't shoot the bolter (not even as single shot) and charge. I also understand that within the 12ps range, I can *only* shoot as rapid fire (two shots)

But within the same 12ps range, can I decide to shoot with the pistol and then charge?
My understanding would be "yes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a model is armed with multiple separate ranged weapons, you only have to follow the restrictions of the ones you use.  So if you choose to fire your Bolt Pistol instead of the Bolt Gun you are free to charge in the same turn.  Pistols have no restriction against assaulting after using them.

If you choose to fire the bolt gun at either its full or rapid fire range you cannot assault.